# Where to upload files other than .blend files and images?

Tags: support, questions, answers, asking-questions

Let's say I want to upload my blend file but due to it being linked to other blend files I have to upload the linked blend files too. blend-exchange doesn't let you upload more than one file at a time neither can you upload .zip files. The addon from [ideasman's answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/47824/14752) only creates a .zip and doesn't really pack the files into the blend file. So should you use services like Dropbox or Google Drive for uploading a zip file (containing several blend files)? Or where should you upload it?

This question refers to [my question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/58347/bge-adding-an-object-linked-from-another-file/). Since the question is about a problem with linked files I can't leave them out. When posting the question with the Dropbox link I knew that links from external sources are not welcome but I couldn't find another way.

Comment: hmm, very good question. This is an interesting edge case that I had not thought of. We normally would say something like "just create a small example file to show the problem" but for file linking you need more then one file.

Comment: This *could* be a hassle, but couldn't you upload each linked blend separately? as long as they are all downloaded to the same directory it should work. All other kinds of linked data can be packed into the .blend.

Comment: @GiantCowFilms You're right, this would work, but it would be more work for both, the one asking and the one answering. Besides that there can be other cases as well. For example if you want to upload a 3D model that isn't a .blend but something like .obj